# Wordpress Theme Development User Defined Image Selection

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a grid of div's with images as the background and overlaying text and buttons.

How do I make it so the admin or editor can select which images are shown in the grid through the customize area when logged into Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

you can make this by theme options, you can give multiple options to your clients by this as well.

https://github.com/mustafa-fazal-hussain/Custom-Theme-Options-WordPress

you can customize this theme option as well.

Comment: this looks like creating a plugin? does this get added to my theme files?

Comment: yes, add this folder in your theme and link theme-options.php in your function.php files

Comment: it has multiple options built in you can modify it according to your need